# Nginx can't access SSL certificates

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, https, docker-compose

Trying to set up an HTTPS server using NGINX and DOCKER. Keep getting the same error while checking nginx configuration file `nginx -t`:

```
2020/11/13 13:37:52 [emerg] 6#6: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Tried copying `certs` dir into `etc/nginx` in `Dockerfile` and it didn't work:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY certs /etc/nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN nginx -t
```

Tried setting up docker volumes as well and still the same error.

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name test;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test;
    ssl_certificate certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key certs/cert.key;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. Permissions of the `certs` are set to 444

```
chmod -R 444 certs
```